# How can build my react app to put in a server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

i just finish my first website using react and I gonna put in my server(hostgator), how can I build it?? thanks

Comment: Your question is too generic. However, you could start by looking at create-react-app (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app), it gives you a minimal template and CLI to develop and build your React apps.

Comment: deploy it to heroku: https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration

Answer (score 2):

if your project just front end code which just JavaScript, html, css. Not backend needed, you can simply put your build folder(npm run build) in your web hosting. Or simplest way to make your website available by using GitHub pages https://pages.github.com/

Answer (score 1):

Did you create it with CRA? In this case just run `npm run build` and put in your server `build` folder by default.